# Azure Chatgpt API giving responses mixed with it's html code

Tags: python, azure, openai-api

i am using chatapi api from azure, but chatgpt giving responses with html code which is not prompted

this is the code, i am using to get responses from chatgpt api

```
    def give_prompt_get_response(self):
        key1='********************'
        endpoints='**************'
        openai.api_key = key1
        openai.api_base = endpoints 
        openai.api_type = 'azure'
        openai.api_version = '2023-05-15'
        deployment_name='aidoos-openai' 
        
        full_prompt = f"{self.prompt} *{self.text_desc}*"
      
        try:
            response = openai.Completion.create(prompt=full_prompt, temperature = 0.85,                 max_tokens=600, engine=deployment_name,)
            chatgpt_response = response['choices'][0].text.strip(" \n")
            #print(f"chatgpt_response {chatgpt_response}")
            return chatgpt_response
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception occured during chatGPT API call: {e}")
```

this is the prompt i am using to get response from the chatgpt
**prompt** = """your are a great Hiring Manager, provide top 5 intent from the job description \n
while preserving its main meaning and ensuring clarity. Focus on using concise language and maintaining coherence \n
your response should be in this format \n
• your response in 15 words. \n
• your response in 15 words. \n
• your response in 15 words. \n
• your response in 15 words. \n
• your response in 15 words. \n
below is project description \n
Don’t justify your answers. Don’t give information not mentioned in the CONTEXT INFORMATION"""

chatgpt is giving html content
**response from chatgp**t:

```
Working Nomads is not affiliated with any of the companies or jobs listed on this site</code></pre>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header"><h5 class="text-center font-weight-bold">Answer</h5></div>

                    @foreach($answers as $answer)

                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li>{{ $answer->answer1 }}</li>
                            <li>{{ $answer->answer2 }}</li>
                            <li>{{ $answer->answer3 }}</li>
                            <li>{{ $answer->answer4 }}</li>
                            <li>{{ $answer->answer5 }}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>

                    @endforeach

                    {{-- <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li><p>Exceptional Node skills using JavaScript</p></li>
                            <li><p>Part of team for the development of the backend components of all Bitfinex Services</p></li>
                            <li><p>Good experience in interacting with databases</p></li>
                            <li><p>Good understanding of security practices</p></li>
                            <li><p>Familiar with microservices architecture</p></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div> --}}

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully received the response from the OpenAI model using the code below.

**Code :**

```py
from openai import AzureOpenAI

client = AzureOpenAI(
  azure_endpoint="<api_endpoint>", 
  api_key="<api_key>",  
  api_version="2024-02-15-preview"
)

message_text = [{"role": "system", "content": """your are a great Hiring Manager, provide top 5 intent from the job description \n while preserving its main meaning and ensuring clarity. Focus on using concise language and maintaining coherence \n your response should be in this format \n • your response in 15 words. \n • your response in 15 words. \n • your response in 15 words. \n • your response in 15 words. \n • your response in 15 words. \n below is project description \n Don’t justify your answers. Don’t give information not mentioned in the CONTEXT INFORMATION"""}]

completion = client.chat.completions.create(
  model="<model_name>", 
  messages=message_text,
  temperature=0.7,
  max_tokens=800,
  top_p=0.95,
  frequency_penalty=0,
  presence_penalty=0,
  stop=None
)

print(completion.choices[0].message.content)
```

**Output :**

It ran successfully and provided the response as follows.

```
C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\Documents\xxxxxxxx>python sample.py
1. Evaluate candidates' qualifications and experience to identify the best fit for the position.
2. Conduct interviews and assessments to determine candidates' skills and suitability for the role.
3. Collaborate with hiring team to define job requirements and develop effective recruitment strategies.
4. Ensure compliance with employment laws and regulations throughout the hiring process.
5. Provide guidance and support to candidates throughout the recruitment process, promoting a positive candidate experience.
```

[image]